# Post Image through Graph API change Via Link

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, upload

I am using a facebook php SDK to post image to users album using the user access token. First we will generate the token and then post the image. My issue is that posting image works fine but below each image on right side, facebook adds a link 'via MY APPLICATION NAME'.This link redirects user to my application page in facebook (http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=APPLICATION ID). I want to change this link to point to my personal website URL (www.abc.com).

Please let me know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen other apps do it, and am looking for the same thing. I've glanced over all the app settings, and am currently reading the api trying to figure it out. It's probably going to be something stupid like deleting all the other urls to force it to default to your site url in the app settings...Let me know if you have any luck with this.